# How to consume generic class T in my different service classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics

I have in my controller a switch block that calls one of my service methods.

each service method has similar response model, but not the same necessarily.

Example of some model response classes:

```
Task<GetCertificateInfoForUserResponse> GetCertificationInfoForUser(string umcn);
Task<GeneralResponseModel> RevokeCertificate(string umcn, KeyType key);
Task<RenewCertificateResponse> RenewCertificate(string umcn, KeyType key);
Task<GeneralResponseModel> DeleteAllCertificates(string umcn);
Task<IssueCertificateResponse> IssueKeys(string umcn, KeyType key);
```

and for example some classes thats named differently than `GenericResponseModel, inherits GenericResponseModel class:

```
public class IssueCertificateResponse : GeneralResponseModel
{
    public const int KeysAlreadyIssued = 12004;

    [JsonProperty("keysUserName")]
    public string KeysUserName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("registrationCode")]
    public string RegistrationCode { get; set; }
}

public class GeneralResponseModel
{
    public const int NoValidCertificate = 12006;
    public const int KeysNotFound = 12003;

    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
        
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

So what I want is to have one varible in my controller, that can be resolved by itslef depending in witch case was entered.
For example:

```
GeneralResponseModel<T> actionResponse;

//call appropriete service
switch (action)
{
    case CertificateAction.Issue2FACertificate:
        actionResponse = await _userService.IssueKeys(umcn, keyType);
        break;
    case CertificateAction.Renew2FACertificate:
        var test = await _userService.RevokeCertificate(umcn, keyType);
        break;
    case CertificateAction.Revoke2FACertificate:
        actionResponse = await _userService.RevokeCertificate(umcn, keyType);
        break;
    case CertificateAction.IssueCloudCertificate:
        actionResponse = await _userService.IssueKeys(umcn, keyType);
        break;
    case CertificateAction.RenewCloudCertificate:
        actionResponse = await _userService.RenewCertificate(umcn, keyType);
        break;
    case CertificateAction.RevokeCloudCertificate:
        actionResponse = await _userService.RevokeCertificate(umcn, keyType);
        break;
    case CertificateAction.DeleteAllCertificates:
        actionResponse = await _userService.DeleteAllCertificates(umcn);
        break;
}

if(action != CertificateAction.None)
{

    //not successfull request
    if (actionResponse.Succeess)
    {
        //something here..
    }
                
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: So, problem is how to declare Generic variable to hold all these various types of classes

Comment: What's wrong with `GeneralResponseModel actionResponse`? Does it need to be generic?

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you can use something like this.

```
GeneralResponseModel actionResponse; // Just remove <T>

//call appropriete service
switch (action)
{
     case CertificateAction.Issue2FACertificate:
        actionResponse = await _userService.IssueKeys(umcn, keyType);
        break;
     ...
}
```

because GeneralResponseModel is your base class and all of your models inherit from it.

You can not use generic classes here. it's because in runtime you can not specify type of T. Let's make an example. consider this

```
XXX result;
if(new Random().Next() % 2 == 0)
    result = new List<string>();
else
    result = new List<int>();
```

what is type of XXX? is it List< string > or List< int > ? Of course XXX is IList but what happens if you want to use its value?

```
System.Collections.IList result;
if(new Random().Next() % 2 == 0)
    result = new List<string>();
else
    result = new List<int>();

if(result is List<string>)
{
    //Do something with string list
}
else if(result is List<int>)
{
    //Do somthing with int list
}
```

you end up with type checking. but if you insist do it with generic classes you can do something like this.

```
public class GeneralResponseModel<T> : GeneralResponseModel
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public T Result { get; set; }
}

public class GeneralResponseModel
{
    public const int NoValidCertificate = 12006;
    public const int KeysNotFound = 12003;

    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
        
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

and in controller

```
GeneralResponseModel actionResponse;

//call appropriete service
switch (action)
{
    case CertificateAction.Issue2FACertificate:
        actionResponse = await _userService.IssueKeys(umcn, keyType);
        break;
    ....
}


if(actionResponse is GeneralResponseModel< IssueCertificateResponse >)
{
}
else if ...
...
```